# Passing values from twitter bootstrap modal, when user click on send button

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a send mail icon coming dynamically based on the users in the database. When User click on mail icon I am calling a function to open bootstrap modal dialog with name (text box) and description (textarea). In my bootstrap modal there are two buttons, one is cancel and another one is sendmail button.When user click on sendmail button, here I am getting confused how to send user description and name as part of ajax request?

```
<?php foreach ($coaches as $key => $coach) {?>
<a class="u-icon-v1" href="javascript:" onclick="openModal('<?php echo $coach['id']?>','<?php echo $coach['name']?>')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="<?php echo $coach['id']?>">
<i class="icon-envelope-letter"></i></a>
<?php } ?>
```

bootstrap modal function

```
function openModal(id,name){    
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
     var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
  var recipient = button.data('whatever')
// How to call call function when user click on sendmail button?
});
```

bootstrap modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Mail To:</label>
            <input type="text" name="mailto" id="mailto" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" readonly="readonly">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message_text" name="message_text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="sendMail()"  id="sendmessage">Send Mail</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does `sendMail()` do? Is that also a script you’ve written?

Comment: No, I just mentioned function name there

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do it. You have already called a method named `sendMail()`. You can retrieve your required values inside that method like below code -

```
function sendMail(){
  //var name = $("#mailto").val();
  var description = $("#message_text").val();

  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data:{mailto: mailto, description:description},
    url: "your url",
    success: function(response){
   }
  });
}
```

When you are calling this `openModal()` function, you can pass your mailto value as 3rd argument like `openModal(id, name, mailto)` & update that input field value using new value & then open  your modal. In this way, this info will be different for each entry. check below code for openModal() function

```
function openModal(id,name, mailto){    
$("#mailto").val(mailto);
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
     var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
  var recipient = button.data('whatever')
// How to call call function when user click on sendmail button?
});
```

Hope now you can do it using this dummy code. Now you can ask what will happen with my modal. Hide it when any get any positive response from your ajax call using `$("#exampleModal").modal('hide');`

Comment: Here the problem is mailto value is coming dynamically. When I place this modal code in foreach loop or outside foreach loop always I am getting same mailto value . When I click on any mail icon bootstrap modal is opening with same mailto value.

Comment: if this is the case then you can pass that value when calling this method & use it.check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, it gave me idea to solve my problem.Thanks again